# Ruby create hash contents by calling methods

Tags: ruby

I've got below methods from which I want to build a hash:

methods:

```
def support_board
  { 'project' => { 'id' => '1234' } }
end

def security_board
  { 'project' => { 'id' => '4352' } }
end

def project_setup
  { 'customfield_12345' => 'None' }
end
```

expected hash:

```
{
  'fields' => {
    'project' => { 'id' => '1234' },
    'issuetype' => { 'id' => '4352' },
    'customfield_12345' => 'None'
  }
}
```

I was trying to something like:

```
{
  'fields' => {
    support_board,
    security_board,
    project_setup
  }
}
```

But this is not correct syntax, I'm getting few errors in console - `unexpected tSTRING_DEND, expecting end-of-input`

Comment: Is `security_board` supposed to return the key `project` or `issuetype`?

Comment: You might want to look into how to dynamically create a hash. There are many methods that can be called upon to manipulate the contents of a hash. A while back I was using "as_json" methods as shown here: http://technicaldebt.com/exporting-mongomapper-objects-to-json/   I would look into merge option and re-think your methods a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Hash#merge!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge) to merge the values in:

```
{ "fields" => {} }.tap do |return_value|
  return_value['fields'].merge!(support_board, security_board, project_setup)
end
# => {"fields"=>{"project"=>{"id"=>"1234"},
# =>    "issuetype"=>{"id"=>"4352"}, "customfield_12345"=>"None"}}
```

Or, in older ruby versions, doing it one at a time:

```
[
  support_board,
  security_board,
  project_setup
].each_with_object({'fields' => {}}) do |method_call, return_value|
  return_value['fields'].merge!(method_call)
end
# => same as above
```

Comment: Per my comment on the question, this assumes `security_board` returns a hash with `'issuetype'` as the key, not `"project"`; if not you'll need to call that method ahead of time, massage the data, and then merge it in

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a syntax error because you need to provide keys when building a hash.

it's ugly, but a working example that would get you past the syntax issue might look something like this:

```rb
{
  'fields' => {
    support_board.keys.first => support_board[support_board.keys.first]
  },
}
```

But this assumes the hashes returned by the methods only have one key/value pair.

If you are able to change your methods, then consider changing their structure to have a structure that might make it easier to access in a more generic way.

Example:

```rb
def support_board
  {
    name: 'project',
    value: { 'id' => '1234' }
  }
end
```

Then you can do something like this...

```rb
{
  'fields' => {
    support_board[:name] => support_board[:value],
    security_board[:name] => security_board[:value],
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1-liner solution (assuming there's a typo in the method `security_board`):

```
{
  'fields' => [support_board, security_board, project_setup].reduce(&:merge)
}
```

There's something to digest in this 1-liner though. You may want to do your research on the following things (all links link to the ruby-doc.org):

- [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Hash.html#method-i-merge)
- [Enumerable#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)
- [Symbol#to_proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) and the unary `&` operator

Well, the documentation of `Symbol#to_proc` is too simple. According to my experience, the implementation of `Symbol#to_proc` may look like this:

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    proc {|obj, *args| obj.send(self, *args)}
  end
end
```

By the way, it also works without the `&` operator.